# How do I clear a collection view cell's view / layer cache during animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, animation

I'm using the Facebook POP library to animate a sign in button. POP works by attaching itself to a layer, and then animates it. When I do this with a collectionview cell, I see the same view right behind it the entire time during animation.

So for example, let's scale it down to a small size:

```
func scaleDown() {
    self.selected = false // just in case?
    self.backgroundView?.alpha = 0 // nil at runtime
    self.selectedBackgroundView?.alpha = 0 // nil at runtime

    let anim = POPSpringAnimation(propertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds);
    anim.toValue = NSValue(CGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80))
    // Sign up view is a UIView subview of the cell showing 
    // the rounded corner button
    signupView.layer.pop_addAnimation(anim, forKey: "size")
}
```

**Initial State**
[image: Initial]

**Finish State**
[image: Finish]

`backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView` are actually both nil during this call I've noticed. So it's not those. What keeps this background layer there and how can I get rid of it, so I can control layer animations within the cell?

Tested on iOS 8.0, 8.1, 8.3

### Update (2/17/15)

I've isolated this to https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

If you set `signupView.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES`, you should see it correctly update itself during animation.

Comment: Then it's possible that your POP library isn't implementing animation on layers correctly.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I just tried using a regular animation block and it did the same thing. I'll keep investigating

Comment: This is turning to be rather unusual. It's not the animation. Just selecting it then reloading data causes it to sick. I've isolated it down to just a collectionview inside a view. I select it and it freezes on the screen despite the cell changes